# Gson only parsing one object correctly from JSON?

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson, inputstream

I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "Person": {

     "id": "1",
     "name": "sampleName"

  },
  "PersonCalender ": {
    "start": "2017-01-25T19:00:00+0100",
    "End": "2019-05-10T19:00:00+0100"

  }
}
```

This is its corresponding `Java` Object (containing 2 objects):

```
public class PersonRequest {
    private Person person;
    private PersonCalender personCalender;

    //getters and setters

    }
```

Below shows how I am trying to `parse` the object, however only the Person object is getting correctly parsed.

Am I making a mistake or is the my `JSON` not valid to be parsed by into this object using `Gson`?

Gson Parsing:

```
 PersonRequest personRequest = new PersonRequest();
        try {
            InputStream is = PersonTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/my/path/personRequest.json");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            personRequest = gson.fromJson(bufferedReader, PersonRequest.class);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.logMessage("Exception: " + e);
        }
```

Comment: There's a space after `PersonCalender` in your JSON - that might be throwing it off. (Also, calend***a***r :p)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two errors here. 1 - space after `PersonCalender`, 2- The first letter in `PersonCalender` should be lowercase (according to your java code)